# How to do `UPDATE...SET...FROM` using knex?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js, postgresql-10

What's the most terse way I can express an `UPDATE...SET...FROM` SQL statement using knex? This is what I've got currently:

```js
  const query =
    knex('user_subscriptions').update(subscription).toQuery() +
    knex.raw(
      ' from plans p where customer_id = ? and p.id = us.plan_id ' +
        'returning us.*, p.name',
      [customer_id]
    );
```

The reason I'm doing this is that I want to efficiently return a field from a related table (JOIN style) without needing a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

As instructed in the official site: [knexjs.org/#Builder-update](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-update)

```
knex('user_subscriptions')
  .returning(['us.*', 'plans.name', 'customer_id'])
  .where({
  customer_id: '?',
  plans.id:  us.plan_id
})
  .update({
    subscription : '?
  })
```

Does:

```
update `user_subscriptions` set `subscription ` = '?' where `customer_id` = '?' and 'plans.id' = 'us.plan_id'
```

Returns:

```
[ us.*: ..., plans.name: ...,  customer_id: ... ]
```